# How configure multiple server nodes to do computation for not-root user?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, non-root-user

Suppose that I have a 4 server nodes but I am not root user. Password-free login has been implemented between nodes.

**If I want to call multiple nodes for computation, how should I configure it， especially for not-root user.**

I know that copy all the things to other nodes may be ok.

Or using shared directory, but for not-root user how to implement it?

Comment: Are you saying you have no root access to install / setup anything?

Comment: @PhilipCouling， just an ordinary user，no `sudo` permission， I only can install something in my home directory.